# PHP read all the contents of row on selection of checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP form as attached.[image: Form with data]. The form entries are pulled from mysql server. On selection of a particular checkbox I need to send all the values to my backend php script. In the image the bottom portion has the output from my php script. I have two issues, which Iam not able to resolve

Issue1:
Get all the details(coressponding rows like externalID,MTdata) on the click of a checkbox.
Issue2:
SelectAll and deselectAll buttons not working. Here how can I pass the ID of the checkbox?

Codes:
PHP form

```
<form target="iframe_b" action="/php_src/first.php" method="POST"
        echo "sending data">

fieldset>
 <legend style="font-size:150%"><b>send MTData</b></legend>
 <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="select_all" name="select_all" value="Select All">
    <input type="button" id="de_select_all" name="de_select_all" value="DeSelect All">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'XXXX';
    $conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("ApplicationServer") or die(mysql_error());
    // Get all the data from the "example" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT EXTERNAL_ID,CONNECTION_STATUS FROM DEVICE_DETAILS") or die(mysql_error());
     echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Selection</th> <th>External ID</th> <th>Device status</th> <th>MT data<th> </tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
        $temp =  $row['EXTERNAL_ID'];
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"id_extID\"  name=\"yourCheckboxName".$temp."\" />";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['EXTERNAL_ID'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['CONNECTION_STATUS'];
        echo "</td><td>";
         echo "<input type=\"textbox\" name=\"textboxName".$temp."\" size=\"50\" value = \"$temp._data\" />";
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
     mysql_close($conn);

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#select_all').click(function() {
        $('#id_extID option').prop('selected', true);
    });


$('#de_select_all').click(function() {
        $('#id_extID option').prop('selected', false);
    });
</script>
```

THanks in advance..

Comment: HTML ID's need to be unique in the page. And you don't need to send all the values to the server: You already have them in the database so you only need the id of the row to retrieve them. And why are you targetting `option` elements? There are none on your page.

Comment: The last column is not in the database. On each selected row I need to get the externalID and the MT data. if I append the externalID to ID tag for the checkbox, how can I make selectall & deselectAll to work?

Comment: can anyone answer this? New to PHP and scratching my head to get it working.